# maven dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.microservice.voucher</groupId>
    <artifactId>voucher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>VoucherMicroService</name>
    <description>microservice project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Angel.SR3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <!-- Stand-alone RESTFul application for testing only -->
        <start-class>com.microservice.service.Main</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data common components -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Testing starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- In-memory database for testing/demos -->
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Eureka service registration -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### This is my pom file

---

i am importing maven project to sts this project is from windows now i'm trying to import to ubuntu.

### error msg like this

```
Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

Comment: can you check your network connections : Could you  reach https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 from browser

Comment: Try to remove repository folder from.m2 folder in your /home/username/.m2 and update the maven project from your eclipse.

Another issue can be that the version you have specified for that dependency is not available now. So try to get the available one.

Comment: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 take me to Index of /maven2/

Answer (score 2):

You will get the above error in two cases

1. If maven central repository does not have the requested jar
2. If you can't access the maven central repository to download.

`Yours is case 2`. I am able to see one of the jar files in the central repository at `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.6/`.

Check your intenet/proxy settings in maven settings.xml file. Enter your proxy host and port values.

I am pasting the sample proxy settings below.

```
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Comment: Configure your proxy settings